# Duplicate dictionary within a list

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want  to duplicate the dictionary within the list and append it back to the list.

```
foci=[
        {
          "label": "Monday 1:00 pm",
          "value": {
            "input": {
              "text": "Monday 1:00 pm"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `deepcopy` the nested dict and append it to the list:

```
from copy import deepcopy

foci = [
    {
        "label": "Monday 1:00 pm",
        "value": {
            "input": {
                "text": "Monday 1:00 pm"
            }
        }
    }
]

foci.append(deepcopy(foci[0]))

print(foci)
```

Comment: how can i make more than 2 copies thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just run the `append` line multiple times in a loop - it will add a copy onto the end of the list each time.

Comment: Thank you so much will mark it as an answer in few moments.